# MySQL SUM Column From Date Ranges

Tags: mysql, sum

How to sum column from each date ranges.

I need to sum the price column & discount column then resulting them based on date rows.

In this case I've selected the **order_id** for **39** and please see the table below.

Here is the **orders** table I have:

```
id      order_id        price       price_disc      date_transaction
1       39              537         25              2014-03-28 11:44:40
2       39              323         0               2014-03-28 16:12:42
3       38              309         11              2014-03-29 15:47:48
4       39              223         16              2014-03-29 19:22:28
5       37              304         19              2014-03-30 23:31:34
6       38              109         7               2014-03-31 09:12:16
7       38              223         0               2014-03-31 17:00:35
8       38              116         9               2014-04-01 20:32:27
9       38              296         0               2014-04-02 16:45:00
10      39              482         20              2014-04-03 12:42:03
11      39              371         12              2014-04-03 20:02:10
12      36              293         13              2014-04-03 21:09:45
13      39              299         0               2014-04-03 23:28:10
14      39              403         22              2014-04-04 08:06:13
```

I want the result like this:

```
date_transaction    total_price     total_price_disc
2014-03-28          860             25
2014-03-29          223             16
2014-03-30          0               0
2014-03-31          0               0
2014-03-01          0               0
2014-03-02          0               0
2014-03-03          1152            32
2014-03-04          403             22
2014-03-05          0               0
2014-03-06          0               0
```

And this is what I've tried but only takes result for date_transaction & total_price only.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date_transaction,
COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) AS total_price
FROM orders
WHERE order_id = 39
AND date_transaction BETWEEN '2014-03-28' AND '2014-04-06' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_transaction, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY date_transaction ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DATE()` function for a date.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT DATE(date_transaction) AS date_transaction,
SUM(price) AS total_price,
SUM(price_disc) AS total_price_disc
FROM orders
WHERE order_id = 39
AND DATE(date_transaction) BETWEEN '2014-03-28' AND '2014-04-06' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(date_transaction)
ORDER BY DATE(date_transaction) ASC;
```

Comment: excellent, if you wanted to show all order_ids just add it to the select and also add it in the group by